# what is the exact keystore securefile path used in yaml script for signing the android app bundle in azure devops when key.properties file is added?

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build.gradle

I added the signing process in the app gradle file (this process is executed only for release build) instead of using Android signing task in my azure pipeline. **I have added a keystore.properties in my project like this and added the my "dev" keystore values as they replaced by my pipeline variables and secure file anyway!**

```
keyPassword=****
keyAlias=****
storeFile=/** jks path **/
```

And the app build.gradle file contains this signing process for release build variant using my properties file :

```
// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
....
android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    //.....
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        //+ specify the signing config
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

And my pipeline YAML script is:
I added this tasks before Gradle@2, copy files and publish artifact tasks in script,

```
steps:
  #get the keyStore file encoded
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: yourNameHere
    displayName: 'Get KeyStore file'
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'yourKeyStore.keystore'
   # rewrite keystore.properties
  - script: |
      printf 'storePassword=%s\nkeyPassword=%s\nkeyAlias=%s\nstoreFile=%s' $(Store.Password) $(KeyStore.Password) $(KeyStore.KeyAlias) $(yourNameHere.secureFilePath) > keystore.properties
    displayName: Generate keystore.properties
```

But the problem is, I'm getting an error while running the pipeline in azure devops:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

**I think, I mentioned the wrong securefile path in my yaml file. If it is related to azure devops securefile path, please tell me path I have to use, if not what is solution to sign the app bundle without using Android signing task in pipeline and also without adding our keystore file in the repo.****